# Parsing JSON File to array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am currently trying to read co-ordinates from a JSON file and save them to an array for further use. However I am not managing to read the file successfully. my JSON file has the following format(I am only concerned with cX and cY):

```
{
    "cX": [
        246,
        1253,
        1464,
        1183
    ],
    "cY": [
        223,
        138,
        383,
        114
    ],
    "scroll": [
        0,
        90,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "sessionID": [
        "f06807c10fb31d5530ad8c4236b94ee2",
        "f06807c10fb31d5530ad8c4236b94ee2",
        "f06807c10fb31d5530ad8c4236b94ee2",
        "f06807c10fb31d5530ad8c4236b94ee2"
    ],
    "Time": [
        "11:30:01",
        "11:30:02",
        "11:30:03",
        "11:30:03"
    ],
    "elem": [
        "H1",
        "H1",
        "H1",
        "BODY"
    ]
}
```

I am attempting to use the following php code:

```
<?php
  $string = file_get_contents("./PHP/JSON/clicks.json");
  $json_a = json_decode($string, true);
  for($idx = 0; $idx < count($json_a); $idx++){
    $obj = (Array)$json_a[$idx];
    echo $obj["cX"];
?>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<?php
  $string = file_get_contents("./PHP/JSON/clicks.json");
  $json_a = json_decode($string);
  $cx = $json_a->cX;
  $cy = $json_a->cY;
?>
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: No need of `true` in `json_decode()` because it will convert object into array .

Comment: Sugges to change this post as it's incorrect: $json_a = json_decode($string, true); results in an associative array and would need to be accessed by `$json_a[cX]`. Trying to access attribute `$json_a->cX` results in null. Suggestion: remove the `true`. Now it cost me 5 minutes to figure out what was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to iterate through an object instead of an array.  If you put square brackets around the json, your script should be working.  Otherwise read the cX and cY properties without iterating through the object

```
$obj = $json_a["cX"];
```